# filter if min sequence number is equal to Status of specific type

Tags: c#, linq

Hey I'm trying to create a filter to see if the next pending step in an ordered process is of type approval.

Each activity has a number 'Sequence' which represents the order of the steps
I need to check if the next one is pending and is of type approval

This is works but its seems really inefficient:

```
public Expression<Func<IPTORequest, bool>> BuildPendingManagerPTORequestFilterByDivision
                                                             (IPublicReadContext context)
{
   return r => r.Activity.ActivitySteps.Any(a =>
                   a.ActivityStepType == ActivityStepType.Approval 
                   && a.Sequence == a.Activity.ActivitySteps.Where(s => 
                                                  s.Status == ActivityStepStatus.Pending)
                                                            .Min(s => s.Sequence)
    );
}
```

The main issues is that the activitysteps is referencing its parent and iterating over the activity steps again.

Does anyone know of a way I can do this more efficiently, without referencing the parent?

Comment: Order them first, then you can check if item [i+1] is pending + of type approval.

Comment: what do you mean  item [i+1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an answer, unless anyone knows of a more efficient way:

```
public Expression<Func<IPTORequest, bool>> BuildPendingOrderedSequencePTORequestFilter
                                                             (IPublicReadContext context)
{
    return
        r =>
           r.Activity.ActivitySteps.Where(s => s.Status == ActivityStepStatus.Pending)
                .OrderBy(s => s.Sequence)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .ActivityStepType == ActivityStepType.Approval;

}
```